# converting data from httpget to data array

Tags: angular

I am new to angular/js and mainly code in c#

the below code uses ag-grid and im trying to take a string of json that I recieve from my c# api, and pass it to the grid. currently when I load the grid I get an error which I believe is caused because the data im passing from the http response is not of the right format for the grid. Does anyone know how I can get the following json into my grid?

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http'
import {AgGridModule} from 'ag-grid-angular';


@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
    title = 'app';
    private gridApi;
    private gridColumnApi;
    private columnDefs;
    private sortingOrder;
    rowData: any; //define a variable that we can store our http request/API data in

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
        this.columnDefs = [
            {headerName: 'Sku', field: 'Sku', sortingOrder: ["asc", "desc"]},
            {headerName: 'Size', field: 'Size'},
            {headerName: 'Quantity', field: 'Quantity'}
        ];
    }

    onGridReady(params) {
        this.gridApi = params.api;
        this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;
        this.http.get("http://localhost:62819/Api/ShippingCalculator/")
            .subscribe(data => {
                params.api.setRowData(data);
            })
    }
}
```

I have tried to  do `data = JSON.Parse` but it says `JSON` cannot be found. Angular seems very useful but I cannot find any kind of info on putting data from http request to a simple grid.

```
{
  "Products": [
    {
      "Sku": "Sku345",
      "Size": "2.0",
      "Qty": "23"
    },
    {
      "Sku": "Sku123",
      "Size": "11.0",
      "Qty": "23"
    }
  ]
}
```

edit: I think it may be something with my json format. How can I take the Products[] array from the json only and assign that to the grid?

Answer (score 0):

Let's try this works!

First change the **field** name for **Quantity** to **Qty** as what you received from the response object to **columnDefs**.

Second instead of passing `params.api.setRowData(data);` pass an array to the rowData `params.api.setRowData(data.Products);`